# PHP multidimensional array to single array sort by value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have one multidimensional array and this array I have to convert into single array with sort. I tried to use `call_user_func_array('array_merge', $ranges);` this function. After using this function get single array. When I use `sort()` function on single array then show output `1`.

My array

```
    Array
(
    [range1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1113
            [1] => 2224 
        )

    [range2] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  500
            [1] => 1112
        )

    [range3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2225
            [1] => 4446
        )
)
```

Use `call_user_func_array('array_merge', $ranges);`
output

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 1113
    [1] => 2224 
    [2] =>  500
    [3] => 1112
    [4] => 2225
    [5] => 4446
)
```

Now I am use `sort()` function then show `1`. Why this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. In `sort()` function, array is passed by reference, and return `true` on success and `false` on failure. So you should apply `sort()` function on the flattened array like this:

```
$array = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $ranges);
sort($array);

// display sorted array
var_dump($array);
```

---

Here's the reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Answer (score 1):

`sort()` function work by reference and returning `true` or `false` so no need to asign result to variable because source variable is changed by reference

Comment: so how can i sort from lowest value to highest value

Comment: @dhanashri sorted array is the same variable as this one provided to sort function.